# Keep text in HTML list indented for wrapped lines while list-style is none

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML list. I want to use an asterisk (*) as the bullets for all items. That's pretty easy by doing this in some CSS:

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li::before {
    content: "*";
}
```

And it's easy to keep the indentation for wrapped lines by doing this:

```css
ul {
    list-style-position: outside;
}
```

However, combining these doesn't work: setting the `content` property of `li` gives the correct bullet, but doesn't keep the indentation for wrapped lines when `ul` has `list-style` set to `none`. How would I combine these to achieve an asterisk-bulleted list that indents wrapped text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to set your li as flex containers. The asterisk and the li's content would be flex items and displayed side by side.

```css
ul {
  font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 1em;
} 
 
li {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: flex;
}
    
li:before {
  content: "*";
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem, dolor facere, architecto ut eaque eius rerum expedita optio repellat reprehenderit voluptates? A numquam voluptatum quasi quidem nisi magni aperiam quam.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem, dolor facere, architecto ut eaque eius rerum expedita optio repellat reprehenderit voluptates? A numquam voluptatum quasi quidem nisi magni aperiam quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem, dolor facere, architecto ut eaque eius rerum expedita optio repellat reprehenderit voluptates? A numquam voluptatum quasi quidem nisi magni aperiam quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem, dolor facere, architecto ut eaque eius rerum expedita optio repellat reprehenderit voluptates? A numquam voluptatum quasi quidem nisi magni aperiam quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem, dolor facere, architecto ut eaque eius rerum expedita optio repellat reprehenderit voluptates? A numquam voluptatum quasi quidem nisi magni aperiam quam.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem, dolor facere, architecto ut eaque eius rerum expedita optio repellat reprehenderit voluptates? A numquam voluptatum quasi quidem nisi magni aperiam quam.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem, dolor facere, architecto ut eaque eius rerum expedita optio repellat reprehenderit voluptates? A numquam voluptatum quasi quidem nisi magni aperiam quam.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem, dolor facere, architecto ut eaque eius rerum expedita optio repellat reprehenderit voluptates? A numquam voluptatum quasi quidem nisi magni aperiam quam.</li>
</ul>
```

https://codepen.io/Jakensen/pen/zYxzYeo

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! Do you have any insight as to why this works?

Comment: @Brosilio, a flex container displays flex children as side by side blocks (except when setting flex-direction to column). Learn more about flex with this [excellent guide by Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add margins to your asterisk:

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li::before {
    content: "*";
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it!
If you use this, this should make them look like bullet points

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li::before {
    content: "*";
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: This was very close, however, the negative margin misaligned the list.

Comment: How do you mean? If i dont have the `-20px` then all the `li`s get pushed over.

Comment: It's very likely that the misalignment is specific to my situation. This list is inside a div with 50% width, centered on the page using `margin: auto`. Your solution pushes the list 10 pixels "off-center" relative to the other text in the div.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way without flex:

In the CSS:

```
/* -- NO BULLET STYLE  --- */   .UL2a { list-style: none; }
/* -- BASIC BLUE DISK ---- */   .LI2a { position: relative; left: 25px; top: 0px; text-indent: -20px; margin: 5px 50px 5px -17px; font-size: 12pt; vertical-align: middle; text-align: left; }
/* -- BASIC BLUE DISK ---- */   .LI2a:before { position: relative; left: -5px; top: 0px; content: "\2022"; font-size: 22pt; vertical-align: middle; color: #00669A; padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px; text-align: left; }
```

In the page:

```
<ul class="UL2a">
<li class="LI2a">J. Allen Hynek wrote <i>The UFO Experience</i> in the year 1972.</li>
<li class="LI2a">When intending the word UFO to be pronounced "yoo-foe", it should be spelled in lowercase. Although less frequently pronounced this way today, it is the original and correct form.</li>
<li class="LI2a">When alluding to the phrase "Unidentified Flying Object" in a generic sense, rather than in reference to an alien craft, use uppercase.</li>
</ul>
```

Hope someone else finds it useful. Please forgive the non-standard formatting. I just find it easier to deal with.